# Pull notifications - is it bad to subscribe/unsuscribe repeatedly?

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I have a question regarding the 'subscribe' operation in the EWS soap api.

Let's say I have a mail application which monitors several folders and I am using pull notifications to syncronize it.
Each time the user enters a folder I need to sync only that folder.
What is more demanding for the exchange server?
Subscribing to every folder I have in the mailbox (In one subscribe operation)or when going from one folder to the next, to unsuscribe the old folder and then subscribe to the new one?

I just want to understand what is more demanding for the exchange. 
Thanks!